# Calling c# program from JScript in MS CRM

Tags: c#, javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I've created a custom button with a custom action in an entity. Now I want the custom action to do something, but I like to do the programming in C# instead of JScript.

How can I make my custom action trigger my code in C# ? As it is possible for plugins, I think it's also possible for custom actions I hope.

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want your C# code to do. If you just want to do some logic within the form in C# because you like it more or are more familiar with it, [this](http://blog.arash.cc/post/Adding-client-side-business-logic-to-CRM-forms-using-Silverlight-managed-code.aspx) might be interesting for you.

If you intend your C# code to do stuff directly related to the database, you should write a web service and call that from your button JavaScript via SOAP.